# django UserChangeForm not rendering "this form" link correctly with form.as_p

Tags: python, django, django-forms, passwords, render

I'm trying to render it with form.as_p and it is rendering mostly as it should. However, the link to the change password section isn't rendering properly. Instead of the blue link on "this form" I get...

"Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user’s password, but you can change the password using this form."
anyone ever deal with this problem?

here's my HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Edit Profile{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Edit Profile...</h1>
<br/>
<div class="form-group">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Update Profile</button>
    </form>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

And my forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django import forms

class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    last_login = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    is_superuser = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check'}))
    is_staff = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check'}))
    is_active = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check'}))
    date_joined = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'last_login', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'date_joined')
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import SignUpForm, EditProfileForm

from members.forms import SignUpForm

class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

class UserEditView(generic.UpdateView):
    form_class = EditProfileForm
    template_name = 'registration/edit_profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserRegisterView, UserEditView
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name="register"),
    path('edit_profile/', UserEditView.as_view(), name="edit_profile"),
    path('password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view())
```

Everything renders properly, except I get this on the page for the password section:

Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user’s password, but you can change the password using < a href="../password/">this form</ a >.

Anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: You shouldn't allow users to change their password from the "Change Profile" section of your website. For changing passwords, Django provides a form already that you can use with a CreateView. `django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordChangeForm`

Comment: Right I understand that. I'm just trying to figure out why the <a> tag isn't rendering properly. I'm going to add the PasswordChangeForm later

Answer (score 1):

In latest versions of Django, help text is not *safe* by default and  `UserChangeForm` was not updated to reflect this change.

In order to obtain the desired output you must override `password` with `mark_safe` in `UserChangeForm`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField, UserChangeForm
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class UserEditView(UserChangeForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(
        label=("Password"),
        help_text=mark_safe(
            'Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this '
            'user’s password, but you can change the password using '
            '<a href="{}">this form</a>.'
        ),
    )
    
    ...
```